# How can I get line by row and column

Tags: lua

So basically I was making a 2d text-type game in lua.

```
local State = {
    "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--",
    "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--",
    "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--",
    "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--",
    "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--",
    "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"
}
```

I made a board like this.

But the problem was... how was I supposed to get the object by the line and column

For example

```
local State = {
    "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--",
    "--", "--", "--", "o", "--", "--",
    "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--",
    "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--",
    "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--",
    "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"
}
```

I want to get the states 4th column, 2nd row which is "o"
How can I do this?

Comment: Or simply `return column+6*(row-1)`.

Answer (score 1):

```lua
local HEIGHT = 6
local WIDTH  = 6

local State = {
    "C1", "--", "--", "--", "--", "C2",
    "--", "--", "--", "o",  "--", "--",
    "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--",
    "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--",
    "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--",
    "C3", "--", "--", "--", "--", "C4"
}


function get_state(r, c)
        return State[(r - 1) * WIDTH + c]
end

for row = 1, HEIGHT do
        for col = 1, WIDTH do
                print(string.format("(%d, %d) -> %s", row, col, get_state(row, col)))
        end
end
```

This implements the generic "Treat a 1D data-structure as a 2D grid" as described here generically, and in another example for C, but adjusted because of Lua's 1-offset tables.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/212808/treating-a-1d-data-structure-as-2d-grid

http://www.bytemuse.com/post/using-a-1d-array-as-a-2d-array-in-c/